# Browser Caching Images on Page Navigation but not on Page Refresh

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser-cache

I have a page that displays some images. The images are each served with the `Last-Modified` header. The results are the same in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

If I navigate to the page through a link or through the address bar directly then requests to the server for the images are **never** sent, instead they are pulled from the browser cache - unless of course it is the very first time the browser has requested the page.

If I refresh the page with the browser refresh button then the images are **always** requested as I would expect them to be, the header is then checked and a 304 is sent back if they are good still or the images are served afresh if they are deemed stale.

Why does navigating to the page behave differently than refreshing the page? I would expect both to fire the requests for the images just the same.

The containing page itself is not cached, only the images on the page. The requests for the page always fire.

What ends up happening is one of the images are modified, the container page is navigated to and the old image is shown unless they refresh the page again.